# Distributing an executable zip file with __main__.py, how to access extra data?

Tags: python, packaging, zipapp

I'm doing a little program and I want to distribute it using this recipe:

1. single directory with `__main__.py` in it
2. zip this directory and adding a shebang on it `#!/usr/bin/env python`
3. making it executable

The problem is that in this package I have also extra files (I'm using pygtk toolkit and I need images and ui xml files). When I try to access these files I have the error that the resource is unavailable (the path that I'm trying to open is something like file.zip/gui/gui.ui ).

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: You're adding the shebang onto the zipped directory?  I don't think python will run with a binary file (zip).  How are you making it executable?

Comment: I'm following this: http://sayspy.blogspot.com/2010/03/various-ways-of-distributing-python.html

in particular:

    `echo "#\!"$(which python) | cat - oplop.zip > /usr/bin/oplop`

Comment: Pygabriel, the method of determining the Python path seems wrong.  Running `$(which python)` like this is generating the path for Python on *your local system*, where you are building the zip.  When you distribute it to others, they may not have Python at the same path.  I would recommend `echo "#!/usr/bin/env python` -- this will execute on the machine you are distributing to and determine the correct Python path at the time the zip/script is invoked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out by myself, It's sufficient to use pkgutil.get_data to access the data inside a package.