# How to find the "current" source file in Python 3?

Tags: file, python-3.x

What's the simplest way to find the path to the file in which I am "executing" some code?  By this, I mean that if I have a file `foo.py` that contains:

```
print(here())
```

I would like to see `/some/path/foo.py` (I realise that in practice what file is "being executed" is complicated, but I think the above is well defined - a source file that contains some function that, when executed, gives the path to said file).

I have needed this in the past to make tests (that require some external file) self-contained, and I am currently wondering if it would be a useful way to locate some support files needed by a program.  But I have never found a good way of doing this.  The inspect module sounds like it should work, but you seem to need a class or function that is defined in that module.

In particular, the module instances contain `__file__` attributes, but I can't see how to get the "current" module.  Objects have a `__module__` attribute, but that's the module *name*, not a module instance.

I guess one way is to throw and catch an exception and inspect the contents, but that seems like hard work.  Surely there is a simple, easy way that I have missed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the absolute path of the current file:

```
import os
os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

Comment: oh!  is it that simple?!  there's a "free floating" `__file__`.  oh!  i guess that is the module's attribute.  i am an idiot.  you would not believe how long i spent looking for this.  thanks! (can't accept for 10mins...)

Comment: @andrew: it is not "free". It is an ordinary module level variable

Comment: @andrew: Please note though, that although this answers the *question*, it's not usually the correct way to do what you **want to do**. This is because the current file can be located inside a ZIP-file, in which case finding the support file that you want will fail. See JF's answer.

Answer (score 3):

To get content of external file distributed with your package you could use `pkg_util.get_data()`(stdlib)  or `pkg_resources.resouce_string()` (setuptools) to support execution from zip-archives or standalone executables created by py2exe, PyInstaller or similar, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5356563/4279).