# log syntax errors and uncaught exceptions for a python subprocess and print them to the terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, stderr

### The Problem

I've been trying to write a program that logs uncaught exceptions and syntax errors for a subprocess. Easy, right? Just pipe `stderr` to the right place.

*However*, the subprocess is another python program- I'll call it `test.py`- that needs to run as if its output/errors are not being captured. That is, running the logger program needs to seem like the user has just run `python test.py` as normal.

Further complicating the issue is [the problem](http://bugs.python.org/issue1927) that `raw_input` actually gets sent to `stderr` if `readline` is not used. Unfortunately, I can't just `import readline`, since I don't have control over the files that are being run using my error logger.

**Notes:**

- I am fairly restricted on the machines that this code will run on. I can't install `pexpect` or edit the `*customize.py` files (since the program will be run by a lot of different users). I really feel like there should be a stdlib solution anyway though...
- This only has to work on macs.
- The motivation for this is that I'm part of a team researching the errors that new programmers get.

### What I've Tried

I've tried the following methods, without success:

- just using `tee` as in the question [How do I write stderr to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe) (failed to produce `raw_input` prompts); python implementations of `tee` that I found in several SO questions had similar issues
- overwriting `sys.excepthook` (failed to make it work for a subprocess)
- [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984428/python-subprocess-get-childrens-output-to-file-and-terminal) top answer seemed promising, but it failed to display `raw_input` prompts correctly.
- the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) seems useful for actually writing to a log file, but doesn't seem to get at the crux of the issue
- custom stderr readers
- endless googling

Comment: how are you required to distribute your program? Are you allowed to use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), a [zip archive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5356563/4279) to pack your program? `pexpect` is pure Python, you could pack it with your program if you are not allowed to install anything.

Comment: Does the subprocess actually have to be a subprocess? Can you run the user-provided code with `execfile` instead?

Comment: @nneonneo Yes it has to be subprocess, because the users' code must have stuff like `sys.argv` behave as expected.

Comment: `sys.argv` is no problem at all. You could replace `sys.argv`. How are you currently running your logger around the user's code? Do they explicitly invoke it? If not, what's your hook?

Comment: @nneonneo Yes, they explicitly invoke it. I know I could just replace it, but I can't think of every similar case when something like that would be a problem.

Comment: I've done this sort of thing before, believe it or not -- I used to work on Python autograding systems. You can have scripts execute in sanitized environments without jumping through hoops, and their code executes as if it was invoked in a separate interpreter. Give it a try -- the flexibility of putting your own code in the target environment lets you do a lot more sophisticated things than you would otherwise be able to do (like introspecting stacktraces and capturing code and execution environment).

Comment: @nneonneo You did all of that using `execfile` !? That sounds very similar to what I'll be doing...

Comment: Technically, `exec`, but it's the same thing (basically). We autograded submissions for a class of over 750 non-CS students (most new to Python, many new to programming) using the first version of the software (which I was hired to develop) and graded everything from interactive programs (fed artificial input from the test harness) to regular functions and classes (which we could call with any arguments to check their responses). We logged all exceptions, warnings, output, etc. and could provide detailed feedback on test failures and exceptions to the students.

Comment: a simplified version of `python -mpdb test.py` might be more robust than unsophisticated `execfile()`- or `subprocess`- based solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @nneonneo 's advice in the question comments, I made this program that seems to get the job done. (Note that currently, the name of the logger file has to by "pylog" for the errors to be printed correctly to the end user.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

'''
This module logs python errors.
'''

import socket, os, sys, traceback

def sendError(err):
    # log the error (in my actual implementation, this sends the error to a database)
    with open('log','w') as f:
        f.write(err)


def exceptHandler(etype, value, tb):
    """An additional wrapper around our custom exception handler, to prevent errors in
       this program from being seen by end users."""
    try:
        subProgExceptHandler(etype, value, tb)
    except:
        sys.stderr.write('Sorry, but there seems to have been an error in pylog itself. Please run your program using regular python.\n')

def subProgExceptHandler(etype, value, tb):
    """A custom exception handler that both prints error and traceback information in the standard
       Python format, as well as logs it."""
    import linecache

    errorVerbatim = ''

    # The following code mimics a traceback.print_exception(etype, value, tb) call.
    if tb:
        msg = "Traceback (most recent call last):\n"
        sys.stderr.write(msg)
        errorVerbatim += msg

        # The following code is a modified version of the trackeback.print_tb implementation from
        # cypthon 2.7.3
        while tb is not None:
            f = tb.tb_frame                                                      
            lineno = tb.tb_lineno                                                  
            co = f.f_code                                                        
            filename = co.co_filename                                              
            name = co.co_name
            # Filter out exceptions from pylog itself (eg. execfile).
            if not "pylog" in filename:
                msg = '  File "%s", line %d, in %s\n' % (filename, lineno, name)
                sys.stderr.write(msg)       
                errorVerbatim += msg
                linecache.checkcache(filename)                                         
                line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)                
                if line: 
                    msg = '    ' + line.strip() + '\n'
                    sys.stderr.write(msg)
                    errorVerbatim += msg
            tb = tb.tb_next                                           

    lines = traceback.format_exception_only(etype, value)
    for line in lines:
        sys.stderr.write(line)
        errorVerbatim += line

    # Send the error data to our database handler via sendError.
    sendError(errorVerbatim)

def main():
    """Executes the program specified by the user in its own sandbox, then sends
       the error to our database for logging and analysis."""
    # Get the user's (sub)program to run.
    try:
        subProgName = sys.argv[1]
        subProgArgs = sys.argv[3:]
    except:
        print 'USAGE: ./pylog FILENAME.py *ARGS'
        sys.exit()

    # Catch exceptions by overriding the system excepthook.
    sys.excepthook = exceptHandler
    # Sandbox user code exeuction to its own global namespace to prevent malicious code injection.
    execfile(subProgName, {'__builtins__': __builtins__, '__name__': '__main__', '__file__': subProgName, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: why do you catch `SystemExit`? it is how `sys.exit()` works. You could use `traceback.print_exception` for `1.` It is easy to mess with the exec-based solutions from inside the subprogram on purpose or accidentally e.g., `import __main__; del __main__.traceback` or `sys.stderr = open(os.devnull)`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Honestly, habit- I guess it doesn't really make sense here. I plan to use `print_exception`. Yeah, that is a really good point; do you think a bunch of resets after the code is run will resolve most of those types of exploits?

Comment: Accidental breakage could be minimized if you save necessary functions as locals e.g., as default parameters to your function, provide the 2nd arg to execfile() e.g., `{"__file__": ...}` (to avoid polluting test.py namespace) and (maybe) use `try/except:` in case sys.excepthook is overwritten.

Comment: @nneonneo How did you handle the types of problems we're talking about in the comments here?

Answer (score 2):

[The tee-based answer that you've linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984428/python-subprocess-get-childrens-output-to-file-and-terminal) is not very suitable for your task. Though you could fix "`raw_input()` prompts" issue by using `-u` option to disable buffering:

```
errf = open('err.txt', 'wb') # any object with .write() method
rc = call([sys.executable, '-u', 'test.py'], stderr=errf, 
          bufsize=0, close_fds=True)
errf.close()
```

A more suitable solution might be based on [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect#Pexpect_version_2.3) or `pty`, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279).

> running the logger program needs to seem like the user has just run python test.py as normal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pexpect

with open('log', 'ab') as fout:
    p = pexpect.spawn("python test.py")
    p.logfile = fout
    p.interact()
```

You don't need to install `pexpect` it is pure Python you could put it along-side your code.

Here's a tee-based analog (`test.py` is run non-interactively):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from threading  import Thread

def tee(infile, *files):
    """Print `infile` to `files` in a separate thread."""
    def fanout(infile, *files):
        flushable = [f for f in files if hasattr(f, 'flush')]
        for c in iter(lambda: infile.read(1), ''):
            for f in files:
                f.write(c)
            for f in flushable:
                f.flush()
        infile.close()
    t = Thread(target=fanout, args=(infile,)+files)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    return t

def call(cmd_args, **kwargs):
    stdout, stderr = [kwargs.pop(s, None) for s in 'stdout', 'stderr']
    p = Popen(cmd_args,
              stdout=None if stdout is None else PIPE,
              stderr=None if stderr is None else (
                   STDOUT if stderr is STDOUT else PIPE),
              **kwargs)
    threads = []
    if stdout is not None: 
        threads.append(tee(p.stdout, stdout, sys.stdout))
    if stderr is not None and stderr is not STDOUT: 
        threads.append(tee(p.stderr, stderr, sys.stderr))
    for t in threads: t.join() # wait for IO completion
    return p.wait()

with open('log','ab') as file:
    rc = call([sys.executable, '-u', 'test.py'], stdout=file, stderr=STDOUT,
              bufsize=0, close_fds=True)
```

It is necessary to merge stdout/stderr due to it is unclear where `raw_input()`, `getpass.getpass()` might print their prompts.

In this case the threads are not necessary too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

with open('log','ab') as file:
    p = Popen([sys.executable, '-u', 'test.py'],
              stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
              close_fds=True,
              bufsize=0)
    for c in iter(lambda: p.stdout.read(1), ''):
        for f in [sys.stdout, file]:
            f.write(c)
            f.flush()
    p.stdout.close()
    rc = p.wait()
```

Note: the last example and tee-based solution don't capture `getpass.getpass()` prompt, but `pexpect` and `pty`-based solution do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import pty
import sys

with open('log', 'ab') as file:
    def read(fd):
        data = os.read(fd, 1024)
        file.write(data)
        file.flush()
        return data

    pty.spawn([sys.executable, "test.py"], read)
```

I don't know whether `pty.spawn()` works on macs.

Comment: What makes it not suitable? Wouldn't those other modules be doing something similar behind the scenes? (I'm reading up on them right now.)

Comment: Also, the `-u` flag doesn't seem to fix the issue. (I'm using your `call` function from the other answer and the code in this one.)

Comment: @MatthewAdams: a program may change other aspects of its behavior in addition to I/O buffering behavior when it detects that it runs interactively (using tty). I've tested it with `test.py`: `print raw_input('input string to reverse')[::-1]` and it works. btw, `raw_input()` prints its prompt to stdout (as documented), not stderr.

Comment: Hmm, when I run that exact `test.py`, the prompt is not printed and instead gets logged to `err.txt`... I see that the main docs says that it prints to stdout, but I definitely read something official that said otherwise yesterday; I'll go hunt around for it.

Comment: Turns out I'm running into [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue1927). So if I add `import readline` to `test.py`, it works as expected. I obviously don't want to have to do that though, because I don't write the input files. (I'm still confused, but you get my upvote back.)

Comment: @MatthewAdams: [`builtin_input()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1607) (Python 3.2) and [`builtin_raw_input()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2016) (Python 2.7) use `PyOS_Readline()` at C level if there is a tty and print to *stdout* in non-interactive case. If `readline` is not enabled then indeed `PyOS_Readline()` prints its [prompt to stderr](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/786aa16aeda5/Parser/myreadline.c#l105). You could add `import readline` to `sitecustomize.py`, `usercustomize.py` if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't edit `sitecustomize.py` or `usercustomize.py` on the machines I have to run this on. (multiuser college computers...)

Comment: I've been working on a `pexpect` solution, but I just learned that it won't be on the machines and... I am not allowed to install it.

Comment: @MatthewAdams: `pip install --user pexpect`.  usercustomize is intended for a user site-package directory (inside your home directory), read http://docs.python.org/library/site.html

Comment: @MatthewAdams: have you tried the  `pty` solution? Have you tried to modify `tee()` to  read/write one byte at a time instead of one line at a time?

Comment: Reading one byte at a time worked great- thanks! Throw that in your answer for an accept.

Comment: @MatthewAdams: I've added the code. It demonstrates how `pexpect` could be used for the task. btw, `pexpect` has liberal license `MIT style -- Free, open source, and all that good stuff`.

Comment: @MatthewAdams: I've added `pty.spawn()`-based solution. It works on Linux. I don't know how well it works on macs.

Comment: That `pexpect` solution captures everything- not just stderr.

Comment: @MatthewAdams: As far as I know there is no way to separate stdout/stderr in `pexpect` (`pty`-based solutions). (remove the accepted mark if the answer is not accepted. `exec`-based seems like the way to go in your case)

Comment: I accepted my answer as the best approach for my specific problem and gave you the bounty as thanks for all your help and for the ton of useful info in your answer.