# execfile() in python , using it for user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, execfile

I am trying to take in a filename from a user and then use `execfile()` to execute the file. Below is my code:

```
print "Please enter the name of the file"
filename = raw_input().split(".")[0]
module = __import__(filename)
execfile(module)             <-- this is where I want to execute the file
```

I understand that `execfile()` works as follows:

```
execfile("example.py")
```

I am unsure on how to do this when the filename is passed as a variable . I am using python 2.7.

Comment: You already import the file, you now have executable code, why the need to run the *module* through the `execfile()` function?

Comment: This is being run in another program , I have no idea what the code is in the program ( whose name the user enters) , so I want to execute it and catch exceptions . Since I do not know what the main is in the undefined function , I need to execute it once

Comment: related: [log syntax errors and uncaught exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12616304/4279).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the import and exec the filename.  You need the .py extension with this method and it will run any `if __name__ == '__main__'` section:

```
filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file: ")
execfile(filename)
```

If you just want to import it, you need to strip the '.py' and it will *not* execute an `if __name__ == '__main__'` section:

```
filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file: ").split(".")[0]
module = __import__(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you , If possible could you just give me a hint on where I went wrong?

Comment: Yes , I apologise for that ,  I stripped it on purpose because of the fact that I do not know if the user will enter the extension .py . so just to be sure I take the input , strip it and append a .py to it