# Python Package With Non-Python Resources? (Not an Egg File [yet])

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out the basic structure for a python program I am writing that must include non-python resources for its functionality. In particular, it includes HTML, CSS, JS, and images that it must *copy out of the package* for report generation. The basic structure currently looks like this:

```
/project
  /my-package
    /sub-package-a
      __init__.py
      ...
    /sub-package-b
      __init__.py
      ...
    /static-content
      stuff.html
      ...
    __init__.py
    util.py
    command.py
```

My basic questions is this: if I, from an arbitrary  directory, run `python my-package/command.py` or `python -m my-package`, how do I get access to the files inside of `static-content`. If I later turn this into an installable egg, does this change?

Comment: related: [python: can executable zip files include data files?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5356563/4279). It works for `python -mmy_package` and eggs too.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That relies on setuptools explicitly. That's not the end of the word, but I'm wondering - is there a builtin python way to do this?

Comment: you'd mentioned eggs so I assumed that you use setuptools. Read other answers from the link, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5356427/4279).