# how to create a built distribution in Python?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, distutils

I have a `Python` project I've been working on for three months, and the project consists of several modules for our team to deploy our software and run scale tests on `AWS`.
Now I want to take the source code, compile that into a binary distribution and bundle all the modules there, like the way python libraries are done. That's for `Unix` systems.
So, suppose one of the modules is called `cluster.py`, the other `scale.py` ... if I wanted to create a cluster in `AWS` I would run:

```
python cluster.py <args>
```

I've been reading about [dist](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html) in Python, and I wanted to do exactly the same how `Python` libraries do:
The user downloads the package, lets say a `.zip` file, and run:

```
python setup.py build
```

then

`python setup.py install`

so the user could from the command line execute:

```
cluster <args>
```

Thus, as I add more functionalities, they would be all bundled up into the package. However, to install all the libraries and other dependencies, I use another python script, called `deploy.py`. So the build step would consist pretty much of running `deploy.py`.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "Tools",
    version = "1.0",
    packages = find_packages(),
    scripts = ['deploy.py', 'cluster.py'],

    # Project uses reStructuredText, so ensure that the docutils get
    # installed or upgraded on the target machine
    install_requires = ['docutils>=0.3'],

    package_data = {
    },

    # metadata for upload to PyPI
    author = "Me",
    author_email = "me@example.com",
    description = "This is an Example Package",
    license = "PSF",
    keywords = "hello world example examples",
    url = "http://example.com/HelloWorld/",   # project home page, if any

    # could also include long_description, download_url, classifiers, etc.
)
```

Comment: Does the title need attention "...create a a built..." ? Unless this is the technical terminology?

Comment: Your users shouldn't care that the command-line utilities are implemented in Python. If all dependencies are pure Python then just [make a single file executable zip named `cluster`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5356563/4279) to be run as `./cluster <args>`. If there are C dependencies then you could use [`fpm`](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) to build native package for your platform. The installation is using `apt-get` or similar.

Comment: If the destination platform has no python installed then the simple executable zip-archive might be not enough, you could use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to bundle python and all other dependencies for the `cluster`, `scale` scripts

Comment: @philippe are you scripts being run automatically when the setup.py file is run?