# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Tags: python, subprocess

I am having hard time parsing the arguments to subprocess.Popen.  I am trying to execute a script on my Unix server. The script syntax when running on shell prompt is as follows:
`/usr/local/bin/script hostname = <hostname> -p LONGLIST`. No matter how I try, the script is not running inside subprocess.Popen

The space before and after "=" is mandatory.

```
import subprocess
Out = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/script', 'hostname = ', 'actual server name', '-p', 'LONGLIST'],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The above does not work.

And when I use shell=False, I get `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error`

Comment: Wild guess: try `'hostname = actual server name'` instead of  `'hostname = ', 'actual server name'`

Comment: Based on how you say you run it at the prompt, it looks like `hostname` is one argument and `=` is a separate argument, which is quite strange. Are you sure there are spaces around `=`?

Comment: hi Bryan, yes there has to be space. Script accepts key=value type argument.

Comment: @user3477108 - that's puzzling, you say there has to be a space but then give a "key=value" example that doesn't have a space. Of course, since your command line example has a space, we know that `key = value` should be 3 arguments to `Popen` as insti shows.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote a little wrapper script around my original script to disregard space around "="  The wrapper script runs fine.

Comment: do you see the shebang line (`#!` -- the first two bytes in the file) at the top of `/usr/local/bin/script` ?

Comment: Hi Sebastian. No I don't see #! in /usr/local/bin/script

Comment: @user3477108: I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27608363/4279) to explain and show how to fix `Exec format error`

Answer (score 155):

`OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error` can happen if there is no shebang line at the top of the shell script and you are trying to execute the script directly. Here's an example that reproduces the issue:

```
>>> with open('a','w') as f: f.write('exit 0') # create the script
... 
>>> import os
>>> os.chmod('a', 0b111101101) # rwxr-xr-x make it executable                       
>>> os.execl('./a', './a')     # execute it                                            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 312, in execl
    execv(file, args)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

To fix it, just add the shebang e.g., if it is a shell script; prepend `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your script:

```
>>> with open('a','w') as f: f.write('#!/bin/sh\nexit 0')
... 
>>> os.execl('./a', './a')
```

It executes `exit 0` without any errors.

---

On POSIX systems, shell parses the command line i.e., your script won't see spaces around `=` e.g., if `script` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

then running it in the shell:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/script hostname = '<hostname>' -p LONGLIST
```

produces:

```
['/usr/local/bin/script', 'hostname', '=', '<hostname>', '-p', 'LONGLIST']
```

Note: *no spaces* around `'='`. I've added quotes around `<hostname>` to escape the redirection metacharacters `<>`.

To emulate the shell command in Python, run:

```
from subprocess import check_call

cmd = ['/usr/local/bin/script', 'hostname', '=', '<hostname>', '-p', 'LONGLIST']
check_call(cmd)
```

Note: no `shell=True`. And you don't need to escape `<>` because no shell is run.

`"Exec format error"` might indicate that your `script` has invalid format, run:

```
$ file /usr/local/bin/script
```

to find out what it is. Compare the architecture with the output of:

```
$ uname -m
```

Comment: I must have accidentally deleted part of my shebang in vim... I was lost until your post.  Thanks.

Comment: @nbro: wrong. Look at the very first code example in my answer. You'll get OSError if there is no shebang. It is the same error as  in [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35216720/4279). There is no error  if you run the command in the shell (no shebang means: "run as a shell script" in this case). `subprocess.check_output()` does not run the shell by default -- no subprocess functions run the shell unless you ask explicitly (if you didn't know that; ask to reopen your question).

Comment: Putting this helped me : #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: @skygeek: such shebang is appropriate only for Python scripts.

Comment: Missing shebang line was the case for me!

Comment: Thank you for the shebang comment! I had a space before my exclamation mark in the shebag declaration and that was causing a tool I was working with to fail

Answer (score 12):

I will hijack this thread to point out that this error may also happen when target of Popen is not executable. Learnt it hard way when by accident I have had override a perfectly executable binary file with zip file.

Comment: that is why my answer recommends `file your-executable` command (it would show that you have a zip archive). Though some zip archives may be proper executables too e.g., [python: can executable zip files include data files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5355694/4279)

Comment: Hijacking this answer to point out this error also happen when trying to execute x86 executable on ARM and vice versa

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
Out = subprocess.Popen('/usr/local/bin/script hostname = actual_server_name -p LONGLIST'.split(), shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Edited per the apt comment from @J.F.Sebastian

Comment: Hi Rchang, thanks for your feedback. It does not work. My script requires space before and after "=". Does your solution provide that?

Comment: This should work okay on this command but is not a good general purpose solution because it doesn't allow you to escape embedded spaces. The `shlex.split` method may be a better choice.

Comment: [do not use shell=True and a list argument together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606653/python-subprocess-popen-woes#comment43638333_27607257)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, you're right of course - thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be wrong to mention that `Pexpect` does throw a similar error

```
#python -c "import pexpect; p=pexpect.spawn('/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl_1.1.0f  version'); p.interact()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 430, in __init__
    self._spawn (command, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect.py", line 560, in _spawn
    os.execv(self.command, self.args)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Over here, the `openssl_1.1.0f` file at the specified path has `exec` command specified in it and is running the actual openssl binary when called.

Usually, I wouldn't mention this unless I have the root cause, but this problem was not there earlier. Unable to find the similar problem, the closest explanation to make it work is the same as the one provided by [@jfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27608363/5014339) above.

what worked for me is both

- adding  `/bin/bash` at the beginning of the command or file you are
  facing the problem with, or
- adding shebang `#!/bin/sh` as the first line.

for ex.

```
#python -c "import pexpect; p=pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl_1.1.0f  version'); p.interact()"
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think the space before and after "=" is mandatory, try it as separate item in the list.

```
Out = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/script', 'hostname', '=', 'actual server name', '-p', 'LONGLIST'],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: downvoted. [Do not use `shell=True` and a list argument](http://bugs.python.org/issue21347) (it is an error in *most* cases).