# Unable to submit python files to HTCondor- placed in 'held'

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am attempting to run a python 2.7 program on HTCondor, however after submitting the job and using 'condor_q' to assess the job status, I see that the job is put in 'held'.

After querying using 'condor_q -analyse jobNo.' the error message is "Hold reason: Error from Ubuntu: Failed to execute '/var/lib/condor/execute/dir_12033/condor_exec.exe': (errno=8: 'Exec format error').

I am unsure how to resolve this error, any help would be much appreciated. As I am relatively new to HTCondor and Ubuntu could any guidance be step wise and easy to follow

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and the latest release of HTCondor

Comment: What do you see if you do a `file /var/lib/condor/execute/dir_12033/condor_exec.exe`?  That is, as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27608363/1718477.

Answer (score 0):

Update, managed to solve my problem. I needed to make sure that all directory paths were correct as I found that HTCondor was looking within its own files for the resources my submission program used. I therefore needed to define a variable in the .py file that contains the directory to the resource