# "OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error" while executing command "ambari-server setup"

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, data-analysis, ambari, bigdata

I have installed Ambari using the steps as provided in

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/installing-apache-ambari-20-ec2-centos-65-instance-using-debu-sinha

However ,I am not able to start ambari server as setup itself is giving me error for below command

## ambari-server setup -v

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/serverSetup.py", line 1013, in setup
  retcode = extract_views()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/serverSetup.py", line 905, in extract_views
  retcode, stdout, stderr = run_os_command(command)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons/os_utils.py", line 98, in run_os_command
  return os_run_os_command(cmd, env, False)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons/os_linux.py", line 45, in os_run_os_command
  shell=shell
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Please help me on this , I am using Oracle VM VirtualBox with CentOs 6.5
[image: Error Screen Shot]

Comment: See if this could help? - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27608363/5708620

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the default JDK libraries installed by ambari-server setup is 64Bit version and my VM was 32 Bit.
I skipped the Oracle JDK installation part and selected option 3 that is custome JDK and gave the JAVA_HOME path as that mentioned in PATH variable we can get it by doing following 
echo $JAVA_HOME
After doing this,it worked fine.