# How can I run this bash script using subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a .sh file, containing a docker command, called *start_deepracer_docker.sh*. When I run it in the following way

```
subprocess.Popen([r"./start_deepracer_docker.sh"])
```

I get the error

> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './start_deepracer_docker.sh'

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the `x` bit set an the script? Does it have a shebang?

Comment: This is the script
docker run -t --rm --name=deepracer -p 8888:8888 -p 5000:5000 --cpus="3" --memory="6g" aicrowd/base-images:deepracer_round2_release /bin/bash

Comment: I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606653/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error but I do not understand in my command where I have to add #!

Comment: You have to add the #!  (shebang) at the start of the "start_deepracer_docker.sh" file with the path to your bash executable. Something like this: `#!/bin/bash`