# How to solve the issue of mismatch between docker image's arch and python3 interpreter’s arch while using Bazel on M1 mac?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, bazel, bazel-rules

I just started to use Bazel with python3 and docker on M1 mac (apple silicon). I already figured out that the python3 interpreter's arch (aarch64) doesn't match the docker image's arch (amd64).
How could I deal with this issue?
It would be appreciated if someone could provide me with any prompts or tips to move forward.

```
% bazel run //projects/xxxx/yyyy:hhhh
...
...
...
... as bazel/projects/xxxx/yyyy:hhhh

% docker run bazel/projects/xxxx/yyyy:hhhh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/projects/xxxx/yyyy.binary", line 392, in <module>
    Main()
  File "/app/projects/xxxx/yyyy.binary", line 382, in Main
    os.execv(args[0], args)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/app/projects/xxxx/yyyy.binary.runfiles/py3_aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/python3'

% bazel --version
bazel 5.2.0
% python --version 
python 3.10.2
```

Comment: Did you check this [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606653/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error) ?

Comment: why did you think it is duplicate ?