# How to make Flask/Jinja2 load bundled templates in an executable zip archive?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, zipapp

I have packaged my Flask web application into an executable Python zipped archive ([zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipapp.html)). I am having problems with the loading of templates. Flask/Jinja2 is unable to find the templates.

To load templates, I used `jinja2.FunctionLoader` with a loading function that should have been able to read bundled files (in this case, Jinja templates) from inside the executable zip archive (reference: [python: can executable zip files include data files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355694/python-can-executable-zip-files-include-data-files)). However, the loading function is unable to find the template (see: `(1)` in the code), even though the template is readable from outside the loading function (see: `(2)` in the code).

Here's the directory structure:

```
└── src
    ├── __main__.py
    └── templates
        ├── index.html
        └── __init__.py  # Empty file.
```

`src/__main__.py`:

```
import pkgutil
import jinja2
from flask import Flask, render_template


def load_template(name):
    # (1) ATTENTION: this produces an error. Why?
    # Error message:
    #   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myapp'
    data = pkgutil.get_data('templates', name)
    return data

# (2) ATTENTION: Unlike (1), this successfully found and read the template file. Why?
data = pkgutil.get_data('templates', 'index.html')
print(data)
# This also works:
data = load_template('index.html')
print(data)
# Why?

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'my-secret-key'
app.jinja_loader = jinja2.FunctionLoader(load_template)  # <-


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000)
```

To produce the executable archive, I installed all dependencies into `src/` (using `pip3 install wheel flask --target src/`), then I ran `python3 -m zipapp src/ -o myapp` to produce the executable archive itself. I then ran the executable archive using `python3 myapp`. Unfortunately, trying to access the the index page through a web browser results in an error:

```
# ...
  File "myapp/__main__.py", line 10, in load_template
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pkgutil.py", line 634, in get_data
    return loader.get_data(resource_name)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myapp'
```

The error is caused by `(1)` in the code. As part of my debugging effort, I added `(2)` to check whether or not the template could be found in the global scope of the file. Surprisingly, it successfully finds and reads the template file.

What accounts for the difference in behavior between `(1)` and `(2)`? More importantly, how can I make Flask find Jinja templates that are bundled together with a Flask app inside an executable Python zip archive?

(Python version: 3.6.8 on linux; Flask version: 1.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

`jinja2.FunctionLoader(load_template)` is looking for a function to return the full `index.html` template as a unicode string. Per the [jinja2 docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#jinja2.FunctionLoader):

> A loader that is passed a function which does the loading. The function receives the name of the template and has to return either an unicode string with the template source, a tuple in the form (source, filename, uptodatefunc) or None if the template does not exist.

`pkgutil.get_data('templates', name)` doesn't return a unicode string, instead it returns a bytes object. To fix this, you should use `pkgutil.get_data('templates', name).decode('utf-8')`

```py
def load_template(name):
    """
    Loads file from the templates folder and returns file contents as a string.
    See jinja2.FunctionLoader docs.
    """
    return pkgutil.get_data('templates', name).decode('utf-8')
```

This means that part (2) will work fine since the code is printing `index.html` as a bytes object. Print can handle a bytes object and it will look almost the same as a string on the console. However, the code in part (1) will fail since it is fed to `jinja2.FunctionLoader` which expects a string. Part (1) failed with a `ValueError` for me.

I suspect that since your error message is a `FileNotFoundError` and calls out `myapp` as the file, that part of your post does not exactly match your application. I replicated the instructions exactly on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu Server 18.04 as well as with Python 3.6 and 3.7 and had no issues aside from needed to use `decode`. I did occasionally run into `PermissionErrors` on Ubuntu which required me to run `sudo python3 myapp`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what accounts for the difference between `(1)` and `(2)` as shown in the code in the question?

Comment: I did some testing and realized I was mistaken about pkgutil. It should be compatible with zipapp. I also tested parts (1) and (2) and both ran successfully after I added the `decode('utf-8')`. Without the `decode`, I got an error message for (1) but it was different than yours.

Comment: Interesting. In my case, `(1)` fails with `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myapp'`, while `(2)` runs successfully. Which OS, Python version, Flask version are you using?

Comment: Python 3.6, Flask 1.1.1, Windows 10.

Comment: I get a `ValueError` without using decode. I only get a `FileNotFoundError` if I try to render something other than `index.html`. In your code, do you have `render_template('index.html')` verbatim? Or could you be inputting `myapp` to `render_template`?

Comment: I have exactly `render_template('index.html')` in my code. My code is exactly the one shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Once you update your code ,you should renew you `myapp`. 
And then you will find that 
 `pkgutil.get_data('templates', name)` always return the context data.

While I try your original code , it was failed because of `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`, which was generated by `app.jinja_loader = jinja2.FunctionLoader(load_template)`
 .

In my opinion, the best way is custom your own `render_template` like this:

```
import pkgutil
import jinja2
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'my-secret-key'
template = jinja2.Environment()


def load_template(name):
    data = pkgutil.get_data('templates', name)
    return data


def render_template(name, **kwargs):
    data = load_template(name).decode()
    tpl = template.from_string(data)
    return tpl.render(**kwargs)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000)
```

---

Besides, here are the suggestions:

1. make a new work direction, and copy my demo code as `__main__.py` and redo the commands to create new zipapp.
2. Don't try to `print(sys.modules["templates"].__file__)` before `pkgutil.get_data('templates', name)`, the module is not loaded util `pkgutil.get_data` by `importlib.util.find_spec`
3. After `pkgutil.get_data('templates', name)`, you maybe debug and get  `sys.modules["templates"].__file__ == "myapp/templates/__init__.py"`
4. In the zipapp , `myapp/templates/` isn't a directory, so it won't work if you try to set `app.template_folder = os.path.dirname(sys.modules["templates"].__file__)`

Comment: I tried your code, but my original error still appears: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'myapp'`. The traceback says that it is caused by `data = pkgutil.get_data('templates', name)`.

Comment: did you rerun `python3 -m zipapp src/ -o myapp` ?

Comment: Yes. `rm myapp`, `python3 -m zipapp src/ -o myapp`.

Comment: did you keep your "templates/__init__.py"

Comment: Yes. `templates/__init__.py` and `templates/index.html` both exist.

Comment: here is my logs ... 
(venv) ➜  [9:41:16] stackoverflow python3 -m zipapp t_60357727/ -o myapp 
(venv) ➜  [9:41:21] stackoverflow python myapp                          
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Mar/2020 09:41:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: In my case I get a traceback and `127.0.0.1 - - [03/Mar/2020 12:34:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -`. Thank you for your effort. I'm suspecting that there is a subtle bug in the lower levels, one that is probably specific to the OS (Ubuntu 18.04) and version combination that I'm using.

Comment: I had added some suggestions , wish to be helpful.