# Python zipapp with data files

Tags: python, jinja2, zipapp

I created a .pyz application, here is the structure:

myapp
┣  templates
┃ ┗  index.j2
┗   main.py

In main program i have this:

```
j2_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates'), trim_blocks=True)
st = j2_env.get_template('index.j2').render()
```

When trying to execute the program I receive error: `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.j2`

How to get access to template directory inside the zipapp? It works perfectly using .py file, outside of package.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357727/how-to-make-flask-jinja2-load-bundled-templates-in-an-executable-zip-archive